# Angular component multiple instance binding input problem

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components

I am using an [Angular Wrapper](https://github.com/mariohmol/ang-jsoneditor/blob/master/ang-jsoneditor/src/jsoneditor/jsoneditor.component.ts) for [JSON Editor](https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor) like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let act of editedActions" class="w-100-p p-24">
  {{act.test_step_id}}
  <json-editor [options]="editorOptions" [(data)]="act.action_json" [(eventParams)]="act.test_step_id" (jsonChange)="changeStepActions($event)"></json-editor>
  <button mat-raised-button class="w-100-p mt-24" color="primary" (click)="editRecordJson(act.test_step_id)">
    <span>Update</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

The problem is that `eventParams` should be different for each editor but it is not varying.

I think problem is this component code (but not sure) (This line is in the component taken from github):

```
@ViewChild('jsonEditorContainer', { static: true }) jsonEditorContainer: ElementRef;
```

The component is behaving like a singleton. Any help?

Edit: I edited this repo and added jsonchange event. Details [here](https://github.com/mariohmol/ang-jsoneditor/pull/58)

Comment: where do you define `jsonEditorContainer` in your template, I can't see it. Also if you want multiple instances from within your `ngFor` you should use ViewChildren

Comment: it is defined in the component in the github link: https://github.com/mariohmol/ang-jsoneditor/blob/master/ang-jsoneditor/src/jsoneditor/jsoneditor.component.ts

Comment: What is `eventParams`? Is an Input\Output of `ang-jsoneditor`? a custom directive? I can't find anything about it.

Comment: I edited it to try if i can get parameter by manually passing to event. It is same for the editRecordJson event.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `@ViewChildren` with a direct reference to the component instead of a template variable string, to get all the JSON editors references:

```
@ViewChildren(JsonEditorComponent) jsonEditorContainers: QueryList<ElementRef>;

// ...

jsonEditorContainers.find(...);
```

It returns a [QueryList](https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList) that allows you to iterate through all `ElementRef`, and monitor the changes with an Observable `changes`.

Comment: But @viewchildren is in the component that is not written by me. It is from open source component.

Comment: Ok I missed that, I modified my answer. I think you should query with `(JsonEditorComponent)` instead of a template variable string `('jsonEditorContainer')` like they demonstrate in the repository readme's example.

Comment: I can get instances of editors. But still event is not sending parameters (or eventParams) dynamicly. How can I know which data is edited?

Comment: Then I don't know how to solve your problem. I have the same questions than PierreDuc, where does `eventParams` come from? If it does not exist on the library's component you cannot bind to it.

Answer (score 1):

What is `eventParams`? What is `jsonChange`? I could be wrong, but data doesn't seem to be two way bindable either, according to the source code.

It seems like you might be looking for something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let act of editedActions" class="w-100-p p-24">
  <json-editor [options]="editorOptions" 
               [data]="act.action_json"
               (change)="changeStepActions($event, act.test_step_id)">
  </json-editor>
</div>
```

You can then read the `test_step_id` in your `changeStepActions` method. If this works, I don't know how you made it compile in the first place.. are you using a `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA`?

Comment: jsonchange is an event added by me. You can see in this pull reuest : https://github.com/mariohmol/ang-jsoneditor/pull/58 . eventparams is just an @input to controller. I tried return it at jsonchage event but it also did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Its not necessary to  use @ViewChildren for that you have to rewrite the entire code of component, make sure while using @ViewChild you pass correct editor reference.

As following

```
@ViewChild('carEditor' ) carEditor: JsonEditorComponent;
@ViewChild('mobileEditor') mobileEditor: JsonEditorComponent;
```

Stackblitz example for refernce :

[Click here for code example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-json-editor-wxyf5t?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

```
To use multiple jsoneditors in your view you cannot use the same editor options.

You should have something like:

<div *ngFor="let prd of data.products" class="w-100-p p-24" >
  <json-editor [options]="makeOptions()" [data]="prd" (change)="showJson($event)"></json-editor>
</div>
makeOptions = () => {
  return new JsonEditorOptions();
}
```